# php extending session expiration

Tags: php, session, session-timeout

So I have looked about on here and web in general and cant find anything for exactly what I need. I have seen a bunch of posts about forcing it to expire after an exact amount of time, but I just want to extend my session lifetime.

I am not sure if it is based on inactivity, or just a set length of time, but it seems that it will lose any session data stored. For example cart data on a shopping basket.

I just want to be able to keep the product data in there for more than what seems like 30 mins, so I have the below included at the top of every script, but it definitely does not last 10 hours.

```
ini_set("session.cookie_lifetime","36000");
ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime","36000");

session_start();
```

I was under the impression that sessions expired when the browser closes, and cookies expire based on time, I dont use cookies, just sessions.

**So my question**, how do I extend the life of my session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a longer session, you may want to consider using cookies (for safe variables only! Never store unencrypted private information in a cookie!).

Assuming the user will want to view his shopping cart at a later time, your  best options are:

1. Enforce account registeration, and save the shopping cart in a database for each user.
2. Use a cookie to store the shopping cart locally on the user's machine.

Do note that some users may disable cookies, so display a big fat warning that your site will fail if cookies are not enabled.

See **[Teh Manual](http://il.php.net/cookies)**

Comment: thanks, was hoping to avoid cookies but looks like its the only option, as sessions seem to vanish without warning which could lose entire carts of data. and yeah no private data :)

Comment: Cookies vanish without warning too, but at least you can control when :) Enforcing user registration is also a good option. It allows you to uniquely identify users and display relevant offers etc based on previous purchases.